# Why doesn't Rust enforce explicitly typed variables by default, despite being similar to C++?

Tags: c++, types, rust

I would assume that using explicitly typed variables can only be a good thing; it improves code readability and also improves preformance by reducing the type-inference work that the compiler must do.

For this reason, I expected the default enforced behavior in Rust to be explicitly defined types. I expected that only in special circumstances, could you opt for an infered type (much like the `auto` type in C++)

However, defining a variable in Rust is done with a `let` expression where you can *optionally* define the type.

To understand why this design decision was made, I would like to know:

By defaulting to defining variables with no type, since the compiler must do extra type-inference, wouldn't this negatively impact compilation time?

What are the stated benefits by the Rust designers of defining types this way?

Comment: "*much like the `auto` type in C++*" - it's arguable, but it's becoming more and more common to prefer `auto` to explicit type specifiers.

Comment: This reads like you are asking for an Opinion, which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: An opinion? Bake him away, toys. I think the title in the question is fine, since it's asking for a historical design decision, which can sometimes be tracked through archived e-mails or other arcane escoterica. The in-text question of "what are the benefits to defining types this way" could be made to sound less opinion based (and more in line with the title question) by changing it to "what are the stated benefits by the Rust designers of defining types this way?"

Comment: The compiler already needs to do all the type inference work in order to check that types agree with, or can be converted to, the declared type, so the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: @mold "at all" according to [this](https://learning-rust.github.io/docs/a1.why_rust.html) one of its *many* influences was `Memory Model and Memory Management: C++, ML Kit, Cyclone`. So at the very least it took inspiration partially from C++ on memory. If you go to the link you'll see that's the ONLY bullet point to list C++; Haskell for example shows up on two bullet points.

Comment: Strong typing and type inference are key features of Rust.  From the Rust documentation, [Influences](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/influences.html).

Comment: I dislike questions like this. In the first place, they tend to have an excellent chance of being unanswerable, because fundamental design decisions are often lost to time, and a bare "we don't know" is an unsatisfying answer. In the second place, they invite speculation and opinion, because anyone can rationalize a decision *post facto* and people tend to have strong opinions about their tools. Thirdly, "why" questions are inherently somewhat weaselly because there's always another "why" underneath, and it's impossible for an answerer to guess which answer will satisfy the asker.

Comment: And finally, I find this kind of question unproductive because why a decision was made in ages past is at best a kind of historical curiosity. It does not tell you what things have changed in the design of the language or scholarly thought since then; it doesn't help you write faster or more readable code; it's roughly as useful as "what color shirt was Graydon wearing when he had this idea?" Now, there certainly is a place for discussion about the relative merits of different designs -- but that is a topic for a discussion forum, not SO.

Comment: `since the compiler must do extra type-inference` I don't think that this will be any more work for the compiler. It anyway needs to check if the value you initialize the variable with matches the type you defined for that variable. So there is a check anyway. And if you don't define the type explicitly it can instead of checking that assignment is valid, use the type of that value to initially set the type of the variable. It would be different if the type of the variable can change as in languages like JavaScript.

Comment: @molbdnilo Rust is inspired by C++. The language was developed to be used in Firefox, so most compiler devs were C++ programmers. The [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/influences.html) says that C++ influenced Rust's _references, RAII, smart pointers, move semantics, monomorphization_ and _memory model_.

Comment: @trentcl: "*I find this kind of question unproductive because why a decision was made in ages past is at best a kind of historical curiosity.*" Those who refuse to learn from history are doomed to repeat it. While this question specifically isn't a good one for this site, actually knowing the answer to the question has practical uses for the design of future languages. Understanding the rationale, one can look at Rust as it is employed and see if the results match the intended goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to quote the first sentence in [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/foreword.html):

> It wasn’t always so clear, but the Rust programming language is fundamentally about *empowerment*

Rust allows you to choose, how explicit you want to be. If you want, you specify the type of almost every variable, but you don't have to.

There are many reasons why automatic type inference is useful, so I'll try to answer some of them:

- When the type is trivial to infer, it would just distract from more important content. Examples:

  ```
  let x = true;
  let y = "hello, world!";
  ```
- The programmer can often figure out the types from the function names and from common conventions, e.g.

  ```
  // `c` is a char
  for c in "hello, world!".chars() {
      let _ = c.is_alphabetic();  // returns a bool
  }
  ```
- The compiler will always choose the obviously correct type, and display an error when it can't infer a type. So omitting types can make your code less readable, but it won't affect it's correctness.

  The only exceptions are numeric literals, which default to `i32` or `f64`, if no additional information is available.
- Sometimes, the type can't be specified explicitly:

  ```
  let closure = |x: i32| 2 * x;  // `closure` has an anonymous type

  fn foo() -> impl ToString {
      String::from("hello, world!")
  }
  let bar = foo();  // `bar` has an opaque type
  ```

  When the `impl_trait_in_bindings` feature is stabilized, we'll be able to specify `bar`s type explicitly.
- One use case is in *macros* like the following, which would become more complicated if explicit types were required:

  ````
  /// Usage:
  /// ```
  /// let map: HashMap<&str, i32> = hashmap! {
  ///     "hello" => 1,
  ///     "world" => 2,
  /// };
  /// ```
  macro_rules! hashmap {
      { $( $k:expr => $v:expr ),* $(,)? } => {{
          // type of `hashmap` is inferred
          let mut hashmap = std::collections::HashMap::new();
          $(
              hashmap.insert($k, $v);
          )*
          hashmap
      }};
  }
  ````